# Wrongly insert data in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysqli

My code previously is success by using "Username" & "Password" data gathering. But I try to add new data to be insert during registration by user, the new data is "Name".

So I already adding the "Name" attribute in the phpmyadmin and the PHP script as well. Unfortunately when I check at phpmyadmin, the data is wrongly inserted in the column.

[image]

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "include/config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $name = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $name_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter Staff ID.";
        $name_err = "Please enter Staff Name.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "Staff ID is already exist.";
                    $name_err = "Staff name is already exist.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($name_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, name, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username,  $param_name, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            $param_name = $name;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: index.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Staff ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span style="color:#FF0500" class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Staff Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                <span style="color:#FF0500" class="help-block"><?php echo $name_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span style="color:#FF0500" class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span style="color:#FF0500" class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="index.php">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username,  $param_name, $param_password);
// Set parameters
$param_username = $username;
$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
$param_name = $name;
```

to this

```
// Set parameters
$param_username = $username;
$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
$param_name = $name;
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username,  $param_name, $param_password);
```

The problem is that in your example none of the `$param_*` variables are initialized before passing them to the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` function.

Can you share the result after this change, please?

EDIT: Assign `$name` variable. Add this code before the SQL statement is prepared.

```
if(empty(trim($_POST["name"]))){
   /* ERROR_HANDLING */ 
} else{ $name = $_POST["name"]; }
```

Comment: "Name" data is not being added into phpmyadmin. 
[link](https://imgur.com/XvU4dfK)

Comment: What happens if you `echo $_POST["username"]` in your script? It seems like it is empty. Can you share the code of your form that is used for capturing the user data please?

Comment: kindly refer to my posting for the script.

Comment: I see your error. You aren't setting `$name` to `$_POST['name']` at any point in your script so it's empty. Therefore you PHP code is doing exactly what it should. I added the block you have to add above.

Comment: Great! Finally, you are my Hero. Thank you so much. [link](https://imgur.com/AbOKlez)